# Is there a way to make __get & __set trigger for defined but empty properties in class

Tags: php

I´ve tried to understand if there is a magic function in php that can trigger a function when I try to access an object property like the following.

```
class User {
      public $groups;

      function loadGroups(){
            $this->groups[] = "a list of groups";
      }

      function __get($name){
             // Trigger on defined property such as groups
             if($name == "groups"){
                 $this->loadGroups();
                 return $this->groups;
             }
      }
}

$user = new User();
foreach($user->groups as $group) // Is it possible to load $user->groups when it's accessed?
      echo $group;
```

I do know that the __get & __set does not trigger if the property is defined in the class even tho the property is set to null or undefined, but is there any other way to trigger something for a defined property or do I have to create getters and setters for all these properties and make sure to always call these when i need to access the property and want to be sure that it's loaded when i access it? I do hope not due to It will result in many changes for the current system I'm working with.

I'm thankful for any information or help I can get to close this chapter.

// ZarToK

Comment: load on __construct ?

Comment: @exussum well that would work ofc, but I don't want to load more then is needed, this was a small example class. The actual class contains a lot of these arrays and fetches it's lists from a database

Comment: Can't you just comment out declaration of $groups in this case, and then in __get determine which one to load.

Comment: I could do that but It would result in a class definition that doesn't tell much about the class itself. For example if I want to generate a documentation.

It might be where I end up but I hope there is an other way :)

Comment: Make the vars `private` or `protected`?

Comment: @AbraCadaver Thanks! This works pretty well. Not really what I hoped for but now the only drawback is that vars that should be public is shown as private/protected but overridden by the __get or __set method. Not the most transparent solution but does what I asked for. I keep this open a while longer if there are some other solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get what you're trying to do, but I don't think you're asking the question right.  You're obviously trying to do lazy loading.

There isn't a magic method for doing what you're requesting, but you can essentially create such a thing.  There are two options: the "creating getters/setters" option - which is more in line with what a Java developer would do, or there's the "protect the variable and use magic method" option which tends to be "nice" for framework apis but can be a little confusing.

```php
class User {
    protected $groups;

    private function loadGroups() {
        $this->groups[] = 'a list of groups';
    }

    public function __get($name) {
        if ($name == 'groups' && is_null($this->groups)) {
            $this->loadGroups();
            return $this->groups;
        }
    }
}
```

alternatively, the more Java way:

```php
class User {
    protected $groups;

    private function loadGroups() {
        $this->groups[] = 'a list of groups';
    }

    public function getGroups() {
        if (is_null($this->groups)) {
            $this->loadGroups();
        }
        return $this->groups;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I'm going with, the protected method, I would recommend the Java way to anyone who has a fresh start but in my case I have to make changes without affecting applications that already use these foreach-loops that I had as example. Thank you @Navarr and also AbraCadaver who mentioned this in a short version.

Answer (score 0):

`__get()` and `__set()` are used for reading/writing data from/to *inaccessible properties*. Inaccessible properties in this case would be `private` or `protected`, never `public`.  If they need to be `public` then what is wrong with just returning from the function?

```
class User {
      public $groups;

      function loadGroups(){
            $this->groups[] = "a list of groups";
            return $this->groups;
      }
}

$user = new User();
foreach($user->loadGroups() as $group)
    echo $group;
```